# jQuery using 'this' to select siblings of it's parent` for slider next prev button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, slider

I have a problem implementing Tiny Slider prev and next button on a single page but with multiple instances and it lays on each of jQuery ui-tabs content (tab-pane).

so, The tabs is not a problem, but each tab wrapped the container for slider with tns-outer class so the .slide-nav element that lies just next to (sibling) on my slider container is now not a sibling anymore but a sibling of the tns-outer (parent) element. The problem is, on the first slide I could make the prev next running just fine. But when the tabs is changed, the next and prev button doesn't work at all.

I use jQuery each and using 'this' to select the element, I'm trying to select the parent of 'this' inside tns object creation function, and if it just use 'this' no errors thrown but if I use jQuery(this) it always give me error.

This code only works on the first slide and the first tab:

```
listingSlider: function(){
  if (jQuery('.listings').length) {
    jQuery('.tab-content .listings').each(function() {
      var slider = tns({
        container: this,
        items: 4,
        slideBy: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        prevButton: '.prev',
        nextButton: '.next',
        nav: false,
        mouseDrag: true,
        gutter: 14,
        responsive: {
          0 : {
            items: 1,
          },
          640: {
              items: 2,
          },

          768: {
              items: 3,
          },

          992: {
            items: 4,
          },
        }
      });
      console.log('bul');
    })
    console.log('slider built')
  }
}
```

Then this code is what I'm trying to do, but it gives me error, I need a way to use 'this' as selector to select it's parent with class .tab-pane and then find a child with class prev / next.
On prevButton, I use this without $ / jQuery, and on nextButton, I use jQuery but all just throws error.

```
listingSlider: function(){
  if (jQuery('.listings').length) {
    jQuery('.tab-content .listings').each(function() {
      var slider = tns({
        container: this,
        items: 4,
        slideBy: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        prevButton: this.parent('.tab-pane').find('.slide-nav .prev'),
        nextButton: jQuery(this).parent('.tab-pane').find('.slide-nav .prev'),
        nav: false,
        mouseDrag: true,
        gutter: 14,
        responsive: {
          0 : {
            items: 1,
          },
          640: {
              items: 2,
          },

          768: {
              items: 3,
          },

          992: {
            items: 4,
          },
        }
      });
      console.log('bul');
    })
    console.log('slider built')
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `this.parent()` should be `jQuery(this).parent()`

Comment: You did it correctly in `nextButton`, but wrong in `prevButton`.

Comment: It's going to select the elements at the time that you're calling `tns()`. if the elements don't exist yet, the selectors won't find anything.

Comment: @Barmar but when I use jQuery(this).xxx there is an Uncaught TypeError: els[i].setAttribute is not a funciton on tiny-slider js. I think the selector can't find the slide-nav next / prev

Comment: You need to end with `[0]` to get the DOM element out of the jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar the [0] solving the issue, thanks again